# Sentencia orderBy no ordena resultados de consulta

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Existe un sistema en el que profesores suben artículos que tienen que ser previamente aceptados por un admin.

> Necesito mostrar solamente a profesores con "Artículos" que estén aprobados y sean públicos, esa lista de profesores necesita estar ordenada por el nombre que está en "User"

Este el query que hice, pero ignora le orderBy():

```js
$designers = Professor::whereHas('user',function($query){
return $query->whereHas('papers',function($query2){
    return $query2->where('private', '=', 0)->where("approved","=",1);
});
})>orderBy('name','asc')->paginate(20);
```

### MODELOS

#### User

```html
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use CrudTrait;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'last_name', 'mobile', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected $table = 'users';
    // protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    // protected $guarded = ['id'];
    // protected $fillable = [];
    // protected $hidden = [];
    // protected $dates = [];

    public function professor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\professor');
    }
    public function papers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\paper');
    }
}
```

#### Professor

```html
class Professor extends Authenticatable
{
    use CrudTrait;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $table = 'professors';
    // protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    // protected $guarded = ['id'];
    // protected $fillable = [];
    // protected $hidden = [];
    // protected $dates = [];

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

#### Paper

```html
class Paper extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    protected $table = 'papers';
    // protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    // protected $fillable = [];
    // protected $hidden = [];
    // protected $dates = [];

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que ya está toda la información

Comment: Se identifica por el usuario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considero que como tienes la consulta es incorrecto, pues al menos la entiendo así:

- Obtienes primero los registros de `User` que tienen al menos un `professor`
  vinculado
- Segundo obtienes los registros de `User` vinculados con al menos un `paper`
- Cuando obtienes los papers entonces usando una función anónima establecemos las 2
  condiciones a través de `where` para filtrar los papers
- En el nivel principal de la consulta ordenamos los registros por el atributo `name`
  de la entidad `User`

Propuesta de consulta

```
$consulta = User::has('professor')
                ->whereHas('paper', function($query) {
                    $query->wherePrivate(0)
                          ->whereApproved(1);
                })->orderBy('name')->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección, gracias